# How to add uneven sub-lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

So lets say I have a list with sub-lists (alignment for visual demonstration):

```
[[1,2,3,4],
[1,2,3],
[0,3,4]]
```

And I want to add them together to get:

```
[2,7,10,4]
```

Originally, for the thing I am working on, I knew an upper bound of these lists, I was thinking about iterating through every sub-list and adding a 0 padding and making each list as long as the upper bound:

```
result+=[0]*(len(upper_bound)-len(list))
```

Then use:

```
result = [sum(x) for x in zip(list1,list2)
```

to get the sum. But the upper bound gets really large (like 10000+) and the number of lists is a lot as well (like 1000+ lists).

My question is: Is there a more efficient method to add N potentially unevenly sized sublists to give a resultant list, or am I asking too much? (I also *cannot* use any fancy numerical libraries like numpy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) can do what you need:

```
import itertools
lists = [[1,2,3,4],
         [1,2,3],
         [0,3,4]]
print [sum(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=0)]
# prints [2, 7, 10, 4]
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  This is the way to do it.